# How to create search facility in laravel?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Today I am trying to upgrade my search facility, at the moment I am listing all the skills available and once clicked it searches for handymens with that skill. Now I want to create a search box so once user inputs anything it will search and display all handymens with that skill once button is clicked. so for example 'p' would return 'Plumber'. But I am struggling hard with it so please help me, if any other files or databases need to be attached please let me know.

Handymen database:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateHandymenTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('handymen', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('street');
        $table->string('postcode');
        $table->string('town');
        $table->string('skills');


        $table->integer('job_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')->on('jobs')->onDelete('cascade');


        $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('handymen', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('handymen_job_id_foreign');
        $table->dropColumn('job_id');
    });
    }
}
```

Skills table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSkillsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('skills', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('skill');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('skills');
    }
}
```

Junction table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateHandymanSkillTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('handyman_skill', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('handyman_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('skill_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('handyman_skill', function ($table) {
            $table->primary(['handyman_id', 'skill_id']);
            $table->foreign('handyman_id')->references('id')->on('handymen')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('skill_id')->references('id')->on('skills')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('handyman_skill');
    }
}
```

View:

```
    <h1>Here you can search</h1>
    <form action="{{url('details')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div>
            <input type='text'  name='skill'/>
        </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Search">
    </form>
     @foreach ($skills as $skill)
        <p>
            <a href="{{url('details/'.$skill->id)}}">{{$skill->skill}}</a>        
        </p>

    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Controller:

```
function search()
{
    $skills = Skill::all();
    return view('layouts/search',['skills' => $skills]);
}
function details($skillId)
{
$skill = Skill::find($skillId);
$handymen = $skill->handymen;
$skill = Input::get('skill');
$result = Handyman::where('skills','LIKE','%'.$skill.'%')
            ->orWhere('email','LIKE','%'.$skill.'%')
            ->get();
return view('layouts/details', ['skill' => $skill,'handymen' => $handymen]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay - lets run through this, I'll give some abstract examples so you can **really** understand how it's working - You're close.

You are able find ALL handyman which have the skills the user has asked for via something like this:

(This assumes the user wants a plumber and they are searching plumbing into the search)

You will want to use Ajax to achieve this, you mention here:

> so for example 'p' would return 'Plumber'.

I am going to assume this means you want to return all of the handy men which have the skill of plumbing.

First things first, chuck some javascript like this in your search page:

```
function up() {
   timer = setTimeout(function(){
            var keywords = $('#skills').val();
            if (keywords.length > 0)
            {
                $.post('/search/handymen', {keywords: keywords}, function(markup){
                    $("#handymen").html(markup);
                });
            }
        }, 500);
    }
    function down()
    {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
```

Markup:

```
 {!! Form::open !!}
 <input type="text" name="searchHandymen" placeholder="Search and follow members" id="skills" onkeydown="down()" onkeyup="up()">
 {!! Form::close() !!}
 <div id="handymen></div>
```

This will have your AJAX set up ready to post to the route /search/handymen. Below I will show you how to get a response & update the page with your results. Be sure to create a **ROUTE** to handle the POST to /search/handymen.

Your method for returning handymen should be something like this:

```
public function searchUsers(Request $request)
{
    $keywords = $request->keywords;

    $handymen = Handymen:whereHas('skills', function ($q) use($request) {
            $q->where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->skill.'%');
        })->with('skills')
        ->get();
    return view('searchedhandymen')->with('searchedhandymen', $handymen);
}
```

The above will constrain your eagarload and should only take handymen which have the skill of the skill you're sending through - You will need to add a name to your Skills table which just represents the name of the skill, **eg: id 1 name plumbing.** This will save you headaches in the future believe me.

Inside of the view searchedhandymen, do your loop of the result ($handymen) and create it as if it belonged on the page as the AJAX request will take that view and inject it directly into the .

Please let me know if anything is unclear. I hope I have helped you solve A problem, i'm unsure if it was the problem you posted though. This will search your handy men.

You may need to establish eloquent relationships on your handymen model btw. A one to many with the skills table will suffice, something like:

```
public function skills()
{
return $this->hasMany(Skills::class, 'skill_id', 'handyman_id';
}
```

the above wont suit your exact table setup but it should set you on the right track.

Let me know if I can help anymore! Thanks!

Comment: I have never done AJAX before so would like to get some more info on how to do that once I type something in the search box and click enter my link get's public/search?searchHandymen=plumber. So the value is gathered, however I get no results, what would the loop look like in searchedhandymen as this is what I am missing and probobly doesn't work because of it